# How to get firestore document list in real time android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to get the firebase document list in real time when a change occur for android 
here is my code

```
firestore.collection("Players").orderBy("deptName").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    documentList.add(document.getId());

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore's documentation gives good examples on how to read/write from it. You can find full Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0)

For your specific need you can head to : [Listen to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collectionauthuser=0)

Here is the code :

```
db.collection("Players")
        .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                    documentList.add(doc.getId());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: my code is working fine but not for real time that is i want to display only document list in an array not it fields

Comment: @Shahzeb I've updated the answer with a copy paste code for your question. The appropriate documentation is on the link above